# win-sshfs "Server HMAC algorithms not found" Can't connect to server

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I'm trying to setup SSHFS from my windows PC to my Debian 8 VPS, however whenever I try to connect with win-sshfs it returns this error:

```
Server HMAC algorithm not found
```

From what limited information I've found on google, this seems to be related to the SSH encryption methods the server is using, however PuTTY and WinSCP have always managed to connect fine to the server via SSH.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: your `sshfs` is probably using different library or codebase then putty/winscp. There must be some configuration for `sshfs` that would force to disable HMAC or use some "known" for your client. Debugging output should help. Also there might be something helpful in the log on the server. What exact client are you using?

Comment: As I said in the title, I'm using win-sshfs, which doesn't seem to have any settings or config outside of what server to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. It had last update in 2012 and version 0.0.1.5 doesn't sound much promising, that it would work reliably. Also on website there are many known problems and TODO list, which consist of compatibility troubleshooting.

There was similar discussion on [StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13875/windows-sshfs-sftp-mounting-clients), which came up with recommending [SFTP Net Drive](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/) or [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) with SFTP capability